# How do I fix Unity crashing after using Unity Tweak Tool to set Window spreading/scaling?

Tags: unity, 11.04, compiz, crash, unity-tweak-tool

The problem:  After setting Window spreading to on in Unity Tweak Tool, Unity will crash on trying to initiate the Window spread/Scale Compiz effect.  This results in the Unity panel and launcher, as well as window decorations disappearing.  How does one fix this issue and stop it from happening?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to work around and fix this problem.  I've seen the same problem as well on Ubuntu 14.04. It seems to be caused by how Unity Tweak Tool handles configuring "Window spreading." (I suspect that it doesn't eliminate a conflict between scale and something in Desktop Wall plugin).  Scale in compiz will do "Window Spreading" without crashing if you enable it there in CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) rather than using Unity Tweak Tool to do it.

First, what you can do without resetting everything right after the crash (some right-clicking and double-clicking still works on desktop in the cases I have seen) is to right-click on desktop, and create a new text file. Right-click on the icon and make it executable using the Properties you can get by right-clicking on the icon and going to the Permissions tab, and put a check in the 'Allow executing file as program' checkbox. (If you cannot do even these you might be able to Ctrl-Alt-F1 to console, logon, and issue `sudo killall Xorg` or issue `sudo service lightdm restart`, and you should be dropped back at the greeter to log back on and start over--or you can Ctrl-Alt-F7, if not).

Next, double-click the icon you created and click Display to open the file with the default text editor.  Put in the file as follows:

```
unity --replace
```

Now save the file.

Then, double-click the file you created, click the Run button in the dialog that should come up, and Unity should be back up and running in a few moments.  Any time Unity crashes you can double-click that icon to bring it back up while you do the following to work around the issue.

Finally, open up CCSM (Compiz) and Unity Tweak Tool.  Turn off Window spread and close Unity Tweak Tool. Go over to Scale plugin in CCSM, and enable it. As soon as you do that, you will get a notice about a conflict between that plugin and something in Desktop Wall (or another plugin, depending upon where the plugin conflict actually is on your machine. Choose to resolve the conflict and choose to disable the conflicting compiz plugin. Then you can go to the Bindings tab and set your hot corner for (screen icon) Initiate Window Picker (Super-w may already be set, but if not you can set it).  Close CCSM.  Trash the icon you created on the desktop, when done.

After doing this I no longer am seeing the crash, no matter how many times I use the Window Spreading/Scale effect, even while writing this (had to try it a few times just to see if I could make it crash while I was writing this--yeah, living on the edge).

The issue isn't in Unity but rather in how Unity Tweak Tool fails to resolve a Compiz plugin conflict when setting Window Spreading. It sets things for the Scale effect but doesn't handle the conflict and disable it.  Someone probably should let the developer of Unity Tweak Tool know about that issue.

Hope this helps those experiencing this same crash.