# Attempting to use or disable window spread causes instant logout

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, window, logout, unity-tweak-tool

Lately, whenever I try to use window spreading, Ubuntu actually logs me out, and I end up at the login screen. I log in again, and everything seems normal, startup applications run, etc., but then if I try to spread windows again, the same thing happens.

I had used `unity-tweak-tool` to set hot corners for window spreading, and I have set a keyboard shortcut using the Super key. Both methods cause this instantaneous logout. But I really do not know if the problem lies with that utility or if it is due to some other reason, as this began weeks after using `unity-tweak-tool` to make these settings, and it was working properly up to this point.

Attempting to disable window spreading altogether (from within `unity-tweak-tool`) also results in the instantaneous logout!

I am using 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.5 (kernel release is 4.4.0-62-generic).

Comment: There's a bug in Unity about this. I'll try to find it.

Comment: Here we go: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1462841. Looks like it might be fixed in 16.04.

Comment: The workaround suggested there did not work for me. When I opened `compizconfig-settings-manager`, I found nothing called "Static Application Switcher" under "Window Management".

Answer (score 1):

Well, after checking out the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1462841) in Seth's comment and also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515334/how-do-i-fix-unity-crashing-after-using-unity-tweak-tool-to-set-window-spreading) regarding a similar problem in 11.04, I was able to solve the problem.

1. Disable window spreading in Unity Tweak Tool. *(Note: this may cause the intempestive logout.)*
2. Install Compiz Config Settings Manager if you haven't got it already.

   `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
3. Run `ccsm`
4. Select "Windows Management"
5. In right panel, tick the box next to **Scale**.
6. Click on **Scale** to open, and select **Bindings** tab.
7. Where you see **Initiate Window Picker**, think "start window spreading".

   My settings:

   - "TopRight" (corner) and <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> for **Initiate Window Picker**
   - "TopLeft" and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> for **Initiate Window Picker for All Windows**.
8. Click the **Back** button, then the **Close** button.

And now window spreading works, whether using hot corners or the keyboard. It was not necessary to reset Unity or do anything quite so drastic as suggested in some sources.